# ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7 Splunk MINT SDK Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, linker-errors, splunk

After adding **Splunk MINT SDK** into existing project, I'm experiencing a linker duplicates now:

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_SSMemoryInfo in:
    /Users/Mac05/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../armv7/SSMemoryInfo.o
    ../SplunkMint.framework/SplunkMint(SSMemoryInfo.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SSMemoryInfo in:
    /Users/Mac05/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../Objects-normal/armv7/SSMemoryInfo.o
    /Volumes/Data HD/../SplunkMint.framework/SplunkMint(SSMemoryInfo.o)
ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here I'm using **Facebook, Google Maps, Google Login and Google Places SDK**'s too.
Please help me with this error.

this the SKD's developer guide site : [Splunk MINT SDK for iOS Developer Guide](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintIOSSDK/5.2.x/DevGuide/Requirementsandinstallation)

Comment: add related framework to Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: @KKRocks can you help me how to get the Link Binary for that??

Comment: did you used pod in your project ?

Comment: No I didn't used. All the SDK added by manual drag and copy only. I added this SDK Under Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: ok then add framework also which are mentioned respective site of SDK. for example see in this **Install Manually**: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/ios-get-started

Comment: Else all SDK's are working fine. After I'm adding this Splunk MINT SDK only this linker error came. I followed all the steps which is mentioned in the Developer Guide.

Comment: can you provide that SDK site link ?

Comment: @KKRocks sure, please check http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/MintIOSSDK/5.2.x/DevGuide/Requirementsandinstallation

Comment: see my answer...

Comment: it's all I done

Answer (score 0):

> Add each of the remaining required frameworks and libraries as
>   follows. Under Link Binary With Libraries, click the + button, click
>   Add Other, select one of the following, then click Add:

```
SystemConfiguration.framework
CoreTelephony.framework
CoreLocation.framework
WebKit.framework
libz.dylib
```

Comment: try to add this SDK using pod . there are many reason related to this issue.

Comment: I'm trying with this method also